# Find common elements from multiple arrays or lists -python

Tags: python

I have multiple groups of lists.  For each group of lists, we have to choose one element from each list in that group.  I am looking for elements that are common between groups of lists.

Both groups of lists are sorted, both within an individual list and between lists belonging to a group.

```
group a (sorted lists, both within and between lists --no elements will be common in a1, a2, a3...)
a1 = [1, 3, 4, 8, 10]
a2 = [12, 13, 15, 19, 20]
a3 = [22, 23, 25]
an = ....
there has to one and only one element from each of a1, a2, a3, ... an ('an' can be upto 1000 lists)

group b (sorted lists, both within and between lists --no elements will be common in b1, b2, b3...)
b1 = [4, 5, 7, 12]
b2 = [13, 15, 17, 22]
b3 = [23, 27, 30]
bm = ....
there has to be one and only one from each of b1, b2, b3, ...bm (bm can be upto 1000 lists)

group c ('a', 'b', 'c' can be upto 20 groups)
c...


one result using groups a1,a2,a3 and b1,b2,b3 is (we want to find all combinations):
[4, 13, 23]

One can brute force this with nested loops, but, it will take too long. 
Minimal example

a1 = [1, 3, 4, 8, 10]
a2 = [12, 13, 15, 19, 20]
a3 = [22, 23, 25]

b1 = [4, 5, 7, 12]
b2 = [13, 15, 17, 22]
b3 = [23, 27, 30]

ab = {}
ab1 = {}
ab2 = {}
ab3 = {}

f = 0
# creating list of lists
a = [a1, a2, a3]
b = [b1, b2, b3]

# no solution because there has to be one element from each list in both groups
if (len(a)!=len(b)):
   print('there is no solution')

# finding common elements    
for xa in a:
   ab1[f] = set.intersection(set(xa), set(b1))
   ab2[f] = set.intersection(set(xa), set(b2))
   ab3[f] = set.intersection(set(xa), set(b3))  
   ab[f] = set.union(ab1[f], ab2[f], ab3[f])
   f = f+1        


for f in range(len(a)):
   if not ab[f]:
       print('there is no solution because this set is empty -- there has to be one element common between groups of lists')

# would like to confirm that this has to be correct because both lists are sorted 
solutions = list(itertools.product(*[ab1[0], ab2[1], ab3[2]]))

# solutions = [(4, 13, 23), (4, 15, 23)]
```

Comment: Are the lists necessarily sorted?

Comment: @Terry Could you give us an example of what you have tried so far? Maybe your brute force solution and the time it takes?

Comment: Do you mean that we need to find a common element in a1, b1, c1, d1, ...., and do the same for a2, b2, c2, d2.... etc?

Comment: @TYeung, I think what he wants is all the different combinations of (A,B,C,..) with A being **one of** the possible duplicates of (a1,a2,a3,...)     But I could be wrong, it's unclear.

Comment: @TYeng --there has to be one element from each list of A and one element from each list of B (and for other groups as well).  It is not necessary that an element in a1 will be in b1 and so on...

Comment: You are looking for `itertools.product`. But do you realize that if you have 5 items per list, and 1000 lists per group, then "all the combinations" in a single group will amount at `5**1000` which is `9.3E698`, i.e. a number with 699 digits?

Comment: @gimix --yes, that is why I am looking for efficient data-structures or algorithm to reduce search space.  Most of the search space is empty (or invalid) - so, this can reduce rapidly.

Comment: @scr posted a minimal working example

Comment: Are the lists sorted? If they are,  you can simply use "two pointers", otherwise you can use binary search tree.

Comment: @TYeung --yes both groups of lists are sorted

Comment: What do you mean by that "it is not necessary that an element in a1 will be in b1"? Any example? Do you mean that if an element in a1 is present in b2, that would still be valid?

Comment: @TYeung --From aforesaid logic, question is updated to: "a1 has to be in b1", "a2 has to be in b2" and so on...  How can I use two pointers or binary search (links to examples would be great)